# why spring boot yaml have to be called application.yml or it can not load successfully

Tags: spring-boot

I want to map yml data to Map object. Below is my yml data(`wikiuser.yml`)

```
spring:
    profiles: default

server: 
    wikiuser: 
        foo: foo@bar.com
```

below is Config object

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="server",locations="wikiuser.yml")
public class WikiUserConfig {
    private HashMap<String, String> wikiuser;
    //...... 
}
```

When start my project, it throws NullPointException, because `wikiuser` is null.

Now changed `wikiuser.yml` to `application.yml` , everything is ok！ Why have to be named `application` even I have specified another name(`locations="wikiuser.yml"`) explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

Because by default spring boot looks for a property or yaml file named `application`. Of course you can override this file name.

If you don’t like `application.properties` as the configuration file name you can switch to another by specifying a `spring.config.name` environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location using the `spring.config.location` environment property (comma-separated list of directory locations, or file paths).

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject
```

or

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

For more details, consult the [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

**Update**: Add `classpath` to your `locations` parameter value, like:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="server",locations="classpath:wikiuser.yml")
```